# MYSQL: How to find the count of tables matching in the foreign key?

Tags: mysql, sql

Having a project for class, do not know really how to explain what I am wondering about but here I go;

Let's say I have a table with a teacher, and one with classes, and I want a view to take out a number of how many classes where class.teacherid=teacher.id AS numberofclasses. Anyone have an idea? Or understand what I am trying to do? Tried to look at SQL but difficult when I don't really know what to call it.

Comment: If i understand you try something like this `SELECT COUNT(*) as numberofclasses FROM Teacher AS t INNER JOIN Class AS c ON c.teacherid = t.id `

Comment: Start an SQL question by showing the schema for all the relevant tables. An example of the data contained in these tables is also very useful. If at all possible create a SQLFiddle with the schema defined and some test data provided

Comment: Thank you, if you know this aswell:

I need this for a website (that is the project), where I hope to search for the name of the teacher, open her site and then see information about the teacher + count of class and some information about her classes, like this:

**Teacher: name. **
**Number of classes: 5**
**List of classes:** 

and then have a list of classes by name, like "english 3B", "spanish 3A", "math 2D".


How would my dataset look like, and how would I eventually need to change the view?

Answer (score 2):

The amount of classes per teacher:

```sql
SELECT teacher.teacher_name, COUNT(class.id) amount_of_classes
FROM teacher
JOIN class ON class.teacherid = teacher.id
GROUP BY teacher.teacher_name
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure how to write the code you need, but try something with [`COUNT`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_count.asp), *e.g.*

```
SELECT COUNT(Class.teacherid)
FROM Class, Teacher
WHERE Class.teacherid = teacher.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, if you know this aswell:

I need this for a website (that is the project), where I hope to search for the name of the teacher, open her site and then see information about the teacher + count of class and some information about her classes, like this:

Teacher: name.
Number of classes: 5
List of classes:

- English 3B *view more*
- Spanish 3A *view more*
- Math 2D *view more*

How would my dataset look like, and how would I eventually need to change the view? I know (I think I know and will manage) to make a site that shows the specific teacher and search for the teacher, but how would i combine columns from three tables?

Class (information about class), Subject (information about the subjects of the classes), Teacher (information about teacher).

Comment: Do not post additional info as an answer - this is not a forum. Move your info into the question text (link "edit" under it) then delete your "answer".